# Replace unique values from nested list with numbers in python

Tags: python, list, nested, unique

How could I replace unique values in nested list with numbers ?

```
sample = [["P1","P13","P2","P2"],
          ["P2","P13P14","P1","P0","P1"],
          ["P1","P0","P3"],
          ["P17","P3","P15P15"],
          ["P1","P5"]]
```

from sample I can create a list of unique values:

```
unique_sample = sorted(list(set(x for l in sample for x in l)))
```

Desired output is to return index from unique_sample for each value in sample nested list

```
output = [[4,0,5,5],
          [5,7,4,0,4],
          [4,3,6],
          [8,6,2],
          [4,1]]
```

Comment: set is un-ordered so the index can change every time you run your code.

Comment: thanks I added sorted in front of list

Comment: @ThomasJohnson, do the actual numbers matter, e.g. can the first row of output be `[[1, 6, 3, 3],...` ?

Comment: i think your answer below is exactly what im looking for just trying to test it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
from itertools import chain

sample = [["P1","P13","P2","P2"],
          ["P2","P13P14","P1","P0","P1"],
          ["P1","P0","P3"],
          ["P17","P3","P15P15"],
          ["P1","P5"]]

d = {j: i for i, j in enumerate(sorted(set(chain(*sample))))}

result = [list(map(d.get, i)) for i in sample]

# [[1, 2, 6, 6],
#  [6, 3, 1, 0, 1],
#  [1, 0, 7],
#  [5, 7, 4],
#  [1, 8]]
```

Comment: This is what I *assumed* the OP meant, but note, it doesn't match their example output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
s  = pd.Series(sum(sample,[])).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
unique_sample = pd.Series(s.index,index=s.values).to_dict()
[list(map(unique_sample.get, e)) for e in sample]
Out[48]: [[0, 1, 2, 2], [2, 3, 0, 4, 0], [0, 4, 5], [6, 5, 7], [0, 8]]
```